Using a measure to filter a map PowerBi
I was recently helped in the creation of a measure that filtered a slicer to allow multiple selections to be combined on an AND situation.
I placed this filter on a report page and it worked fine for the production of a data table but when I add a map onto the page the filtered table is not reflected on the map.
I have looked at various places to place the filter, on the visual or on the page but because it uses a measure it doesn’t work on the map.  Any ideas?
He is the link to the original post
Power BI change slicer logic from OR to AND
